# Pandas - Get the average year (mean of days across multiple years)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas time series dataframe with hourly data distributed over a 20 years period (N = 175297):

```
Data                A        B      C       D

1/1/1989 0:00     10.0    14.0    18.0   20.0
...
12/31/2008 5:00   11.9    11.9    11.9   11.9
```

I need to compute "a mean year" - the average value of each day of all years (1-366)

I have used the following code line:

```
result = data.groupby([data.index.month, data.index.day]).mean()
```

In the output the first two columns of values ​​are correct (A and B) but the last two are equal (C = D),and they should be quite different.

How can I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Your code looks good. Why do you think the `C` and `D` should be different?

Comment: The problem was in the input data. I was not using iloc correctly, Thank you